# Call functions polymorphically outside of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Say I have a bunch of storage classes `X1`,`X2`,,,`Xn`.
Say I have `Writer` class that provides `write()` functions for each one of the storage classes:

```
class Writer
{
public:
  void write(const X1& x);
  ...
  void write(const Xn& x);
};
```

Now I have to add more storage classes as follows:

```
class B;
class D1: public B;
class D2: public B;
```

to be initialize as follows:

```
B* d1 = new D1();
B* d2 = new D2();
```

Now I need to enhance class Writer to include the following functions:

```
void write(const B* b);
void write(const D1* d);
void write(const D2* d);
```

But this will not work as I intend. Calling `write(d1)` does not invoke `void write(const D1* d)`. I'm losing the ability to call `write()` polymorphically.

seems to me like this is a job for [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not that experience in this pattern and might got it wrong).

Regardless of whether `visitor pattern` is the way to go or not, are their any other suggestions for resolving this?

#### Notes

1. `Writer` is a complex class that write storage classes to binary files. None of the storage classes needs to be aware of the way they are serialized to a file. Storage is separated from the writing process.
2. `dynamic_cast` is an oblivious solution but I'd like to avoid that. it is not clean and besides, what if I have a lot of derived classes.

Comment: 1) visitor 2) add virtual `write` hook to classes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Is their a way to avoid this? classes `B`, `D1` & `D2` are the exception. I feel a bit reluctant to change the entire design just to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get around this with double dispatch:

```
class Writer
{
public:
    void write(const B* x)
    {
        x->on_write(*this);
    }

    void accept(const D1* x);
    void accept(const D2* x);
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual void on_write(Writer& x) = 0;
};

class D1 : public B
{
public:
    void on_write(Writer& x) override { x.accept(this); }
};

class D2 : public B
{
public:
    void on_write(Writer& x) override { x.accept(this); }
};
```

Comment: that is in fact the `visitor` pattern which is a an elegant solution. what bothers me in that approach is that `B`, `D1` & `D2` are now aware of a writing process. we add some irrelevant function to the interface just to be able to overcome a problem in a different class. I'm still not convinced it is the optimal solution.